# Do I need to define the backward() in custom loss function?

Tags: python-2.7, torch, pytorch

I have already to define my own loss function. It does work. The feedforward may not have problem. But I am not sure whether it is correct because I don't define the backward().

```
class _Loss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, size_average=True):
        super(_Loss, self).__init__()
        self.size_average = size_average
class MyLoss(_Loss):
    def forward(self, input, target):
        loss = 0
        weight = np.zeros((BATCH_SIZE,BATCH_SIZE))
        for a in range(BATCH_SIZE):
            for b in range(BATCH_SIZE):
                weight[a][b] = get_weight(target.data[a][0])
        for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
            for j in range(BATCH_SIZE):
                a_ij= (input[i]-input[j]-target[i]+target[j])*weight[i,j]
                loss += F.relu(a_ij)
        return loss
```

The question I want to ask is that

1) Do I need to define the backward() to loss function?

2) How to define the backward()?

3) Is there are any way to do the index of the data while doing SGD in torch?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a loss function like below.

```
def mse_loss(input, target):
            return ((input - target) ** 2).sum() / input.data.nelement()
```

You do not need to implement backward function. All the above parameters of the loss functions should be PyTorch variables and the rest is taken care by `torch.autograd` function.

Comment: Thank for your help. But what if I want to write the backward? I know how to use the chain rule to calculate gradient but I don't think I can write the derivative for each weight or bias in the neural network. Do you have some guidance.

Comment: Once you calculate a pyTorch Variable , calling backward function will create the gradients for all the dependent variables. You do not need do it manually.